# Generate a simulated data matrix for a given convariance

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, statistics, computer-science, python

I have the covariance matrix, let's call it `Z` of size `pxp`.

I want to come up with a matrix `X` of generated data and of size `nxp` that satisfies three conditions:

1. The columns are normally distributed.
2. The columns are centered at 1.
3. The matrix of covariance for `X` is `Z`.

I am looking for both mathematichal and algorithmic way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. People here like to see the effort you made. Could you edit your post to include some of your thoughts? Also, have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Comment: A vector has a covariance matrix. What's the covariance matrix for a matrix?